# How to slice a list and store as a multiple list based on condition python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, slice

I have list of more than 1000 strings that i would like to slice the lists into sublists based on condition. for example I have list that looks like.

```
my_list = ['pdf', 'csv', 'csv','csv','txt','txt','txt','txt','pdf','pdf','csv','txt','txt','pdf', 'csv', 'csv','pdf','csv','txt','txt' ]
```

into multiple sublists. The condition for slicing is that how much time the words repeating as sets. Each sublist should be increased with sorted set, In actual case i have more that 1000 strings.

so the final results look like

```
lst_1=['pdf', 'csv','txt']    
lst_2=['pdf', 'csv','txt']
lst_3=['pdf', 'csv']
lst_4=['pdf', 'csv','txt']
.
.
so on...
```

i have some thing like below which gives error.

```
arrays = [[my_list[0]]]
for i in range(1, len(my_list)):
    if 'pdf','csv','txt' in i:
        arrays[len(arrays)-1].append(my_list[i])
print(sorted(set(arrays)))
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
my_list = ['pdf', 'csv', 'csv','csv','txt','txt','txt','txt','pdf','pdf','csv','txt','txt','pdf', 'csv', 'csv','pdf','csv','txt','txt' ]

counter = [0,0,0]
counter[0]=my_list.count('pdf')
counter[1]=my_list.count('csv')
counter[2]=my_list.count('txt')

l2=[]
lists = []
pdf,csv,txt=counter

for i in range(max(counter)):

    l2=[]
    if pdf>=0:
        l2.append('pdf')
        pdf-=1
    if csv>=0:
        l2.append('csv')
        csv-=1
    if txt>=0:
        l2.append('txt')
        txt-=1

    lists.append(l2)

print(lists)
```

output:

```
[['pdf', 'csv', 'txt'], ['pdf', 'csv', 'txt'], ['pdf', 'csv', 'txt'], ['pdf', 'csv', 'txt'], ['pdf', 'csv', 'txt'], ['pdf', 'csv', 'txt'], ['csv', 'txt'], ['csv', 'txt']]
```

hope this helps you!

Comment: This doesnt give sorted nested list.

Comment: @DarshanMahalingeGowda it gives a nested list! can you explain how your list should be sorted.

Comment: As you have given the output it should look same as that but now i'm getting more nested lists with only [['csv'],['csv'],['csv'],['csv'],['csv'],['csv'],['csv']] by taking your example only i should get only 4 sets of nested lists but in your case its giving 8.

Comment: @DarshanMahalingeGowda what is your list that you are giving to the  program

Comment: list is same as i have asked in question but in actual i have more that 1000 strings in a list and i know that it has 5 sets with 1000 repeated strings only so i should get only 5 set  nested lists. @Prathamesh

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count the number of occurrences and then recreate the list if you need it.

```
counter = [0,0,0]
for i in my_list:
    if i == "pdf":
        counter[0] += 1
    elif i == "csv":
        counter[1] += 1
    elif i == "txt":
        counter[1] += 1
```

Then after you know how many of them, you can loop over the lowest counted string and create lists.

```
lists = [['pdf', 'csv','txt'] for i in min(counter)]
```

Comment: Hi this gives out an error saying tuple object does not support item assignement @mahmut asım Onat

Comment: Okay changed it to list. Tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple dictionary for counting.

```
myDict = dict()
for s in my_list:
    if s in myDict:
       myDict[s] += 1
    else:
       myDict[s] = 1
lists = [['pdf', 'csv', 'txt'] for i in range(min(myDict.values()))]
```

The above code counts the number of occurance of each element in `my_list` and creates another list of list. You might need a little modification to get the output you want since it is not clear what exactly should the output be

Comment: This gives an error saying 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: I added a range() to fix that error. Can you explain again what output are you expecting?

Comment: i should get nested lists of sets.